# Python: What is the most efficient recursive output method?

Tags: python, performance, recursion

I want to make a function which returns a list of all possible n-bit binary numbers in a recursive manner. Since I am a starting computer sience student I was given multiple solutions to this, but my question is which of those methods is the most efficient (and preferably why). Also, if anyone can come up with another method which is even more efficient (it has to be recursive, not iterative), feel free to add it as an answer!

These methods (not in any order) were given to me:

> Build-up

```
def rec_output2(n, s = ""):
    if n == 0:
        return [s]
    else:
        sol_zero = rec_output2(n-1, s + "0")
        sol_one = rec_output2(n-1, s + "1")
        return sol_zero + sol_one
```

> Expand

```
def rec_output3(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [""]
    else:
        l = rec_output3(n-1)
        new_l = []
        # we pull iteration inside
        for s in l:
            new_l += [s + "0"]
            new_l += [s + "1"]
        return new_l
```

> Expand and build-up

```
def rec_output4(n, sols = None):
    if sols == None:
        sols = [""]
    if n == 0:
        return sols
    else:
        new_sols = []
        # we pull iteration inside
        for s in sols:
            new_sols += [s + "0"]
            new_sols += [s + "1"]
        return rec_output4(n-1, new_sols)
```

Because this is the first year that I'm attending the course, my teachers don't want to bother me with performance issues yet, but since I am very interested in this matter I'd like some clarification. Thanks in advance!

*Excuse my lack of perfect English, my native language is Dutch.*

Comment: Your code has indentation errors.  Please fix those.

Comment: You can measure each function execution time using module https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: You are asking about the most efficient (then for a more convenient), then say you don't care about performance.  Perhaps you should think about what you actually are looking for in an answer.

Comment: this is probably something for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tripleee - Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have edited my post to clarify my question. I am indeed trying to get **performance** out of the function, not convenience. The _not bothering_ was a wrongly constructed English phrase. I hope it's better now. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Performance here will probably be affected more by how you're building the strings and lists than by how the recursion is performed. For example, using `''.join` to build the strings instead of repeatedly adding them can have a much bigger effect.

Comment: @interjay thanks for the clarification. On the other side of things, which of the three methods would be most used/accepted in the community? Or is there no real difference?

Comment: Benchmarking them shows that the first is slower than the other two.

Comment: The "most used/accepted in the community" would be to use existing functions, e.g. `[''.join(a) for a in itertools.product('01',repeat=n)]`. Otherwise, go for the simplest one unless you know that it is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: I did not know about the power of _itertools_ yet, it seems! Thank you for the comment, it really helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to profile the code, but in general generators can outperform manual iteration.

```
def gen(bits):
  if bit == 1:
     return ["0", "1"]

  smaller = gen(bits - 1)

  return ["0" + b for b in smaller] + ["1" + b for b in smaller]
```

This, admittedly, uses both iteration and recursion.

Comment: It's okay to use iteration as long as the main body is made up of a recursive function. Thanks for the alternative, I will look into it :)

Answer (score 1):

One first step toward performance improvements would be to [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) your code. This will prevent the redundant re-computation of (lists of) strings that have already been computed.

Comment: Would the best way of doing this be using _dictionaries_ or _lists with tuples as elements_?

Comment: Memoization won't help with the given functions. The recursive calls will not repeat previously-calculated values.

Comment: I think interjay is right, but still thank you for the contribution Robert!

Answer (score 0):

Build-up is the least efficient, the other two are almost equal.
and of course Vatine's code is the most efficient.